# Vue JS component not working in blade page

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I want to load vue component in laravel blade file, but my changes are not reflected in laravel blade file. my vue file content is not loaded into blade file, example component return empty. There is no error in console, please help me to solve my problem.

```html
  **Blade file**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/example.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  
<example></example>
      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**

```js
**example.js**

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
**

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**Example.vue**

```
<template>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Example Code</h1>                    
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your js code like below way

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'

import Example from "./components/Example"

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: { Example },
});
```

Then you have to build the assets. Run below command

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it doesn't work. It shows blank page and no error in console.

Comment: I have pasted it after testing at my end. Could you please tell me how you managing the process? Did you build properly? Did you install npm module? Did you generating the js properly while building from webpack?

Comment: yes sir I have installed npm module and js in webpack

Comment: Then you have to debug. I already tested and it works at my end.